# JQuery methods wont work with MOTW

Tags: html, jquery

I have 2 html pages. One of the page say page-2 is using some JQuery methods, because of which I am seeing Internet Explorer Information bar with message “To help protect your security, Internet Explorer has restricted this webpage from running scripts or ActiveX controls that could access your computer. Click here for options.”. After adding Mark of the Web “**MOTW**” to the page-2, I am able to avoid seeing Internet Explorer Information bar.

**Issue:** If I try to display these pages in two different frames, then Jquery methods of page-2 won’t work. If I open the page-2 independently, then Jquery methods works fine and will not see Internet Explorer Information bar also. Only when I tried to display the pages in frames then Jquery methods won’t work. Any thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

Is the jQuery being loaded for both the pages when you open in two frames??

Comment: I am new to HTML and JQuery. Not sure how to load JQuery. I am using following code to display both the pages.`<frameset cols="50, *" frameborder="0">
      <frame src="ProjectInfo/menu.html" /> 
   <frame src="ProjectInfo/resultDetails.html" name="Content"/>
 </frameset>`